# compute daily log returns for a [saddle] Series[DateTime, Double]

Tags: scala, saddle

Given a Series of price data (using scala's saddle library), is there a simple way to compute the log returns?

```
type DtPxSeries = Series[DateTime, Double]

def pxDifs(series, DtPxSeries) : DtPxSeries = {
    (series / series.shift(-1)).dropNA
}

// px_data is a `Series[DateTime, Double]`
val px_difs = pxDifs(px_data)
```

I can pass a series (`px_data`, which uses joda DataTimes as the index) to `pxDifs` which returns a series of day-on-day ratios: so far so good...

But how might I now compute the log() for each element in `px_difs`?

```
import breeze.numerics._
// fugly
log(px_difs.values.toSeq.toArray)
```

Using the above I can use breeze to do the computation but (ideally) I'd like to be able to get a new `saddle.Series` -- using the original DateTime index

Am I missing something??

Grateful for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
px_difs.mapValues(v => Math.log(v))
```